# What methods are available to an :object in a partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, partial

I am trying to build my partials and repeat less, but I am having a problem.  The following works just fine:

In view:

```
<%= render 'valve' %>
```

In partial:

```
<% if @valve.length > 1 %>
<h3>Valve kit</h3>
<%= render 'not_enough' %>
<% else if @valve.length < 1 %>
  <h3>Valve kit</h3>
```

I am going to have many kits, so rather than repeating this for every kit variable, I would like to do something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'valve', :object => @valve %>

<% if valve.length > 1 %>
<h3>Valve kit</h3>
<%= render 'not_enough' %>
<% else if valve.length < 1 %>
  <h3>Valve kit</h3>
```

But that breaks the valve.length method.  So, what is changing when I pass @valve as the :object?  Is there another method I can use as a substitute to accomplish the same functionality in the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a :locals hash to the partial

```
<%= render :partial => 'valve', :locals => {:valve => @valve } %>
```

Then use valve.* in your view like you have. Try to avoid using instance variables in partials when possible.

Comment: Yeah, something didn't feel right about using instance variables inside of the partial.  It kinda defeats the purpose of the partial I guess.  That worked great.  Can you maybe point me to something that explains why this works?

Comment: Hahahahahaha that's funny. Are you new to Rails? There's no documentation :). Here (stackoverflow) is the best place actually (other than google). If you know ruby, you can browse the source, but otherwise you are stuck looking here :). Can you upvote and mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem? :)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I am quite new to Rails.  I have had all kinds of success just googling around for answers to things with the exception of architecture type questions and this piddly little question.  I am going to mark it, but when I tried, it told me I have to wait a few minutes.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize your reputation was low ;). They make you wait when you are less than 10. As for Rails, its REALLY annoying at first, but once you get past all the caveats, it's amazing. I recommend learning Ruby FIRST though. Download and play with Ruby in console. It REALLY helps when coding in Rails. Remember that Rails is a Framework ON Ruby :)

Comment: I don't see how there couldn't be any documentation? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html comes to mind. Sure, they're far from perfect. But there IS documentation. Assuming Rails 3. If you are using Rails 2.x: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: There are *examples* but not documentation as to WHY, which is what he was asking. To know HWY, you have to look at Ruby code

Comment: @Seth That's true. I was skeptic about being to explain "why" it works, so I thought it was the examples he wanted nevertheless. Reading the code for the partials, though, I realized it could be done in a meaningful way. I'm sorry. +1